# Allow empty parameter in MVC route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, string

I've got a route that should only ever called by an automated process:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "Automated file processing",
  "Process/{change}/{file}/{type}",
  new { controller = "C", action = "Process" }
);
```

Where both the `file` and `type` are optional parameters. Ideally, I'd like to be able to call

```
/Process/Created/Filename/Text    (with file and type)
/Process/DirectoryListing//Text   (with type only)
/Process/Created/Filename/        (with file only)
```

How would you acheive that optional parameter in the middle? With the example route I showed, even if I add `file = "", type = ""` to the route, I get:

> HTTP Error 400 - Bad Request.

Comment: I had a similar problem I posted about here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743431/need-help-canonicalizing-an-http-get-form-in-asp-net-mvc. Basically, Darin is right. Only the last parameter can be optional.

Comment: See this, http://bit.ly/dem6F5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have optional parameters in the middle of route. For obvious reasons only **the last** parameter can be optional or the routing engine cannot disambiguate between the different possible cases.

Answer (score 1):

your answer lies here: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/20/routing-regression-with-two-consecutive-optional-url-parameters.aspx

It discusses the problem and also provides a workaround,
hope it helps!

Comment: Sorry, that article discussed a completely different problem in MVC 3.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add `file = UrlParameter.Optional, type = UrlParameter.Optional`

For an optional middle parameter I would define another route before this one.

Comment: I think `file = UrlParameter.Optional` fixes the case where both are missing, but not the case where I've got a missing middle parameter (and `//` in the url). How would I define that other route? `Process/{change}//{type}` doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah, that is not going to work. You can do ..../file-{file}/type-{type}, query string parameters or something of that nature.