# How can I get an HTML DropDownListFor to post back?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm building a custom pagination mechanism and I have a dropdown for changing the page size. The page size is represented in my viewmodel. Obviously I can change the value and run the search again to get the appropriate results.

But is there a way to make the DropDownListFor post back when the selected value is changed?

Comment: asp.net mvc was meant to get away from doing `!Page.IsPostBack`. Look into simply doing an HttpPost in asp.net mvc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I actually wrote a little javascript to startup this behavior:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').find('select.auto-post').change(function () {
        $(this).parents('form').submit();
    });
});
```

Funny coincidence, I'm actually [working on the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743431/need-help-canonicalizing-an-http-get-form-in-asp-net-mvc) right now. However, I would suggest that you don't use the POST HTTP method for any kind of paging parameters. Use GET instead. This makes navigation easier for your users, and it makes it easier for search engines to index all pages of your content.

**UPDATE:**

For the above jquery to work, you would render your dropdownlist like this:

```
Html.DropDownListFor(expression, items, new { @class = "auto-post" })
```

Comment: So many years later, I googled my own question and I am impressed with my newbie tendencies. The solution I ended up going with was triggering a call through GET to toggle the new data. Essentially what you are proposing by just throwing everything on the query string. Probably could have also been accomplished through clever use of the ViewModel

Answer (score 14):

You can use HtmlATtributes passing "onchange();" Try this.

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProductName, listobj,
                               new { onchange = 'submit()'; }) %>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 for the helper-integrated solution.  Just what I was looking for.  The syntax works better in MVC with double quotes and without the semicolon: `new { onchange = "submit()" }`