# how to allow the bad url in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

i want to pass a parameter in url blank but localhost server tell that it is bad url. are i can make them work in MVC 3

the url is

```
http://localhost:6251/time/saturdau/first/second//nextparameter
```

you can see that third parameter is blank here. are this request can work whenever 4th parameter pass without passing 3rd paramter.

what i do to make this work.

Comment: the question shouldn't be "why cannot i do this bad thing", the question should be "why ARE you doing this bad thing?" is there an actual reason for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rather put a work around on this say you make a convention if the parameter passed is null you may try passing something like my_conventional_null_indicator

so instead of making it look like this

```
http://localhost:6251/time/saturdau/value1/34//70
```

do this

```
http://localhost:6251/time/saturdau/value1/34/my_conventional_null_indicator/70
```

but the best way would still be the conventional way

```
http://localhost:6251/time/saturdau?param1=value1&param2=34&param3=&param4=70
```

or the much better way is to maximize the capability of the RouteValueDictionary.

Answer (score 0):

This is not allowed. You can have optional parameters, but they must be the last segment in the URL. You can't have an optional parameter in the middle.

Comment: yeah i thing about it but 4th param is pagenum and third the value about the thing they want.

Comment: A workaround would be to remove the page number from the route and grab it from the query string instead.

Comment: ...or you could default the page number to 1. I wrote a post with a similar problem at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743431/need-help-canonicalizing-an-http-get-form-in-asp-net-mvc