# ASP.MVC default route value matching issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I'm debugging a route matching issue in ASP.NET MVC. The URL is defined like this: {foo}/Somewhere/{controller}/{action}/{id}. Each segment has a default value set up on the route.

When I try to browse http://hostname/bar/Somewhere the route matches. If I try http://hostname/Somewhere (thus, omitting foo segment), the route doesn't match.

I've installed routedebugger from Phil Haack and I can see that my defaults are correctly set up (controller = Home, action = Index, id = UrlParameter.Optional, foo = bar), but the route still does not match and I get a 404.

I tried to modify the route to have no "optionnal" segment before the "static" segment, like this: Somewhere/{controller}/{action}/{id}/{foo}. With this route, both url (http://hostname/Somewhere/bar and http://hostname/Somewhere) are working as expected.

Is there a limitation (or a bug) in MVC that I can't use an "optionnal" segement before an hard-coded one?

Thanks for your help,
Fabian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only logical. Your `foo` placeholder cannot be suddenly empty or omitted. And if you ask my opinion, I must say it would not be a good thing to omit. These route, in decreasing order of size, must map to your app's modules and functionality.

Basically, as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447190/allow-empty-parameter-in-mvc-route) question also answers, you cannot have optional segment in the middle of the route.

Comment: I don't understand why it can't be omitted as I provide a default value for it.

Comment: Because that is how it is designed, and mainly for performance reason.